# How to select exact JSON data from mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

```
var sql = 'SELECT user_desc.language' +
'FROM user_desc ' +
```

Struggling with the Where operator, current thought process:

```
sql += 'WHERE JSON_VALUE(user_desc.language, "$.english") = "true"'
```

This is obviously wrong (returns undefined), but you get the idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

Example how data is saved in database:

```
{"russian":"false","english":"true"}
```

Comment: It works here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9fa7e7d38af0a7ae059480e23ed9f079 . `This is obviously wrong (returns undefined), but you get the idea of what I'm trying to achieve` , No, you should always include data examples and expected result

Comment: In addition it is always great to include the version of the RDBMS you are using; especially with a question having `JSON` functionality. The version may require a different function or query as an answer.

Comment: Don't forget that searching and selecting records based on JSON data can be rather inefficient. Especially in this case, where there doesn't seem to be a need for JSON data. A simple [SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set.html) would do the same, but far more efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are probably tons of different ways to do this.

You could try using `JSON_SEARCH` which is in MariaDB 10.2

The [documentation here provides the full details](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search), but here is an example:

```sql
Select
u.language
, Json_Unquote(Json_Extract(u.language, '$.english')) As json_language
From user_desc u
Where Json_Search(u.language, 'all', 'true') Like '%.english%';
```

You could then wrap this in a [JavaScript string literal perhaps instead of concatenating](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#es6-template-literals) as well.

> Edit: Adding [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=d57b7c28349b34dbac6c9f14bb0b9c5f) using MariaDB 10.3 instead of MySQL 8.0 made by [@Ergest-Basha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16461952/ergest-basha) with the quickness.